# Why does Sencha Touch use Ext.scroll.Scroller?

Tags: performance, extjs, sencha-touch

From what I understand, Sencha Touch uses Ext.scroll.Scroller to handle momentum scrolling behaviour consistently across all mobile platforms. But what I don't understand is why this is nessecary. Ext.scroll.Scroller does not handle scrolling performance consistently across all platforms (BB10 scrolling performance is atrocious, while Android performance is not bad).

Why doesn't Sencha just delegate scrolling to the device's browser/webview instead of using Ext.scroll.Scroller? For example, it seems weird that an Android Sencha app should have elastic scrolling like in iOS when native Androids apps don't have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It utilizes GPU acceleration when scrolling, thus makes it faster on some platforms. You could bypass it by setting scroller to false, then turn on overflow: auto in CSS. If you're getting substandard performance on BB10, perhaps you could do it just there.